# "Application failed codesign verification" on non-wildcard provisioning on Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

On Xcode 4.2, I could validate the binary signed with wildcard provisioning, but not the non-wildcard provisioning (for push notification).

Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: What about certificates?

Comment: iPhone Distribution cert is valid. That's why I could build the valid binary with wildcard provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

For push notifications, you have to have a unique app id (without *).
Only App IDs with a specific bundle ID can be used with the APNs. You cannot use a “wild-card” application ID.